# PHP Query to get information using Inner Join (SQL)

Tags: php, sql

I've been trying to make a query work for my student database but I seem to be getting thrown a 'No Column exists' error.

I am trying to display the ModuleID, ModuleName, Credits in a table for a specific user. 
Student table contains an ID which is linked to a bridge table between 'Student' and 'Modules' - the link table is called 'StudiesModules' with foreign keys of StudentID and ModuleID.

My statement is trying to query to show all of these values in a table which will then be run into my HTML.

I cant get the query to work - I have tried this:

```
SELECT Modules.ModuleID,  Modules.ModuleName, Modules.Credits 
FROM (Modules INNER JOIN 
      StudiesModules 
      ON Module.ModuleID = StudiesModules.ModuleID
     ) 
WHERE StudiesModules.StudentID = "433943";
```

Here is the table (with CSS etc.) that I want to place it into.

http://jsfiddle.net/mfwYS/4308/

I'm not sure why i'm so unable to do this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried to remove the parentheses?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Add the ddl, sampledata and expected result

Comment: *cant get the query to work*  can you descibe in Detail you get an Syntax error, wrong data?

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
SELECT m.ModuleID,  m.ModuleName, m.Credits 
FROM Modules m,StudiesModules s 
where 
m.ModuleID = s.ModuleID and
s.StudentID = "433943";
```

Comment: Do not suggest these old syntax for join. Also this should give exactly the same result as OP's query

Comment: Also some people will downvote answers with just comments like *try this* or *this will work*, please add some explanation to show why this will work.

Comment: @NigelRen . . . Such people are not going to change anyone's behavior unless they provide a comment explaining why they don't like the answer.  In fact, a comment along is probably sufficient without the downvote.  Can I downvote a downvote with "laziness" being the reason?  That said, I would speculate that the downvote is due to the archaic `join` syntax and not to the lack of explanation.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I agree about comments.  Wish I didn't have to post comments like above, but I try and explain why people downvote (although it's still a guess) I'd rather leave a comment as it's more direct.  Perhaps a ratio should be set per user of the number of downvotes per day without a comment.  (also the old syntax was already commented on by 1 user)